# Using a straw filled with electrolyte as stylus?

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen

Now what I understand is our human body or a stylus disturbs the electrostatic field of a capacitive screen and thus the mobile calculates the disturbance and does some math and registers a touch.

Now what if I take a thin tube and fill it with some kind of electrolyte (like Vinegar or Salt Water) then put a cotton swab on one end and then use it as a stylus. What will happen...?

Edit: So I tried it with Normal Tap Water. So I had a bit of mixed results sometimes it worked sometimes it didn't. And it did get messy. Now I have to somehow make it efficient.

Comment: Try it at home. Your screen will get wet.

Comment: Whatever you do, you need to match the impedance of the human body, it is possible, but may take a lot of experimentation.

Comment: What's the other end of the tube connected to? You may make an artificial finger, but it has to be connected to an artificial carcass.

Comment: @laptop2d: No, you don't need to "match the impedance of the human body". All you need to do is provide a conductive path to the human body. An electrolyte-filled tube can do the job just as well (if somewhat more messily) as a metal rod or a carbon-loaded elastomer. For example, the [Saw Stop Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wiy5i75oP_U) shows that a hot dog makes a good stand-in for a finger. It'll make your phone screen all greasy, however.

Comment: @DaveTweed What about the capacitive sensors? It's my understanding that you have to match the same capacitiance and resistance of the human finger.

Comment: @laptop2d: No, the finger does not have capacitance of its own. Remember, the human body is basically a hundred-pound bag of electrolyte to begin with. It's the capacitance of the whole thing to the world at large that the screen is sensing.

Comment: I tried it with tap water. As you guys said my Tablet did get wet. But I had a bit of mixed results Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.